# Flutter UI with Stacks and Position

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface

I'm trying to create [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/5828720-Movie-App-Homescreen).

I got very close and so far I'm able to achieve [this](https://ibb.co/znMkGjg).

here is my code

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text(
            'Now Playing',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),

          // Stack of Movie Cards
          SizedBox(
            height: 300.0, // Adjust the height as needed
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                  Positioned(
                    left: i * 30 - 50, // Adjust the spacing between cards
                    child: Transform.scale(
                      scale: 1.0 - ((i - 5).abs() / 5.0) * 0.4,
                      child: Card(
                        elevation: 4.0,
                        child: Image.network(
                          'https://via.placeholder.com/180x180', // Replace with movie poster URL
                          width: 180.0,
                          height: 180.0,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Now I have 2 questions:

1. how to position the widgets in a better way esp without hardcoding?
2. Suggest a way to position the card after card num five. from 6 the cards must be stacked below (in the reverse manner of how a usual Stack works)